# Way to more efficiently rewrite a huge amount of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

working with a CMS here so the source code off-limits. The page in question is a gigantic table of time listings like so.

```
<div class="body-time">8:00 pm - 9:00 pm</div>
```

Now imagine that but with dozens if not hundreds of entries.

The issue is that in the feed we pulled the data from is set in UTC time. Our event is in a timezone that needs to be five hours backwards.

**Question**:

I need to do a mass rewrite of text elements.

The best thing I can think of is finding and replacing the text like so:

```
$(".body-time").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('8:00 pm', '9:00 pm');
});

$(".body-time").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('9:00 pm', '10:00 pm');
});
```

However that is going to be redundant and heavy on a page if I had to rewrite text in 30 min blocks for every single time entry.

Is there a way to more efficiently rewrite the text? A mass find and replace of sorts? Everything needs to be -5 hours.

Comment: You'd be better off changing the time server-side, and then outputting the correct time; then you wouldn't have to make any client-side manipulations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how efficient doing a find+replace for hundreds of elements would be.

As a commenter said, it might be more beneficial for you to solve the problem before the time is ever written to the page. Regardless, it's still possible to do what you're asking in a more efficient way.

Firstly you should note that you only need one selector function as jquery will apply it to all elements that match that class.
From there you just need to convert the time to -5 hours. A library such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) might be useful here, but here I'll show you a way to do it with no extra plugins.

First you [split the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) in half over the `" - "` character to extract the two times.

From there for each time string you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [string matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract the hour, minute, and time of day. Then simply subtract 5 from the hours and adjust the time of day accordingly. Then put the string back together. In the below example I just used a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to do so.

Finally join the string again using `" - "`.

```js
$(".body-time").text(function () {
  const timeStr = $(this).text()
  const times = timeStr.split(" - ")
  // you could use momentjs for this next part if you like
  const newTimeStr = times.map(time => {
    let [, hour, minutes, m] = time.match(/(\d):(\d{2}) ([ap]m)/)
    hour = (parseInt(hour) - 5) // subtract 5 hours
    if(hour <= 0){
      m = m === 'pm' ? 'am' : 'pm'
      hour += 12
    }
    return `${hour}:${minutes} ${m}`
  }).join(" - ")
  $(this).text(newTimeStr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body-time">1:00 pm - 2:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">2:00 am - 3:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">3:00 pm - 4:00 am</div>
<div class="body-time">6:00 am - 7:00 am</div>
```

There shouldn't be any need to write a long page of jquery selectors. You might also want to modify this algorithm depending on your other requirements or if your actual page is structured differently than your question, but I hope this helps you get the gist of how you can optimize your approach.

**EDIT**

Here's a more condensed version that does the same thing using only [string#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```js
$(".body-time").text(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/(\d):(\d{2}) ([ap]m)/gi, (full, hour, minutes, am_pm) => {
    hour = (parseInt(hour) - 5) // subtract 5 hours
    if (hour <= 0) {
      am_pm = am_pm === 'pm' ? 'am' : 'pm'
      hour += 12
    }
    return `${hour}:${minutes} ${am_pm}`
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body-time">1:00 pm - 2:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">2:00 am - 3:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">3:00 pm - 4:00 am</div>
<div class="body-time">6:00 am - 7:00 am</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression with the replace-method. Inside the replacement callback you have to take care of times that switch between am and pm. But i think it could be a little heavy on the performance.

```js
$(".body-time").each(function(index){
  let textContent = $(this).text();
  let modifiedText = textContent.replace(/(\d*\:\d*) ([\w]*)/gi, function(match, p1, p2, offset, string){
    let time = p1.split(':');
    let hour = parseInt(time[0]);
    let minute = parseInt(time[1]);
    let modifiedHour = (hour + 7) % 12;
    if (modifiedHour < 10) {
      modifiedHour = '0' + modifiedHour;
    }
    if (minute < 10) {
      minute = '0' + minute;
    }
    let am_pm = modifiedHour > hour ? (p2 == 'am' ? 'pm' : 'am') : p2;
    return modifiedHour + ':' + minute + ' ' + am_pm;
  });
  $(this).text(modifiedText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-time">8:00 pm - 9:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">10:30 pm - 11:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">8:00 pm - 10:30 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">11:00 pm - 1:00 am</div>
<div class="body-time">2:00 pm - 3:30 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">3:30 pm - 3:30 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">8:00 am - 9:00 am</div>
<div class="body-time">11:00 am - 11:30 am</div>
<div class="body-time">4:00 pm - 6:00 pm</div>
<div class="body-time">10:00 am - 10:30 am</div>
```